# How to get a list of properties inside of entity in JPA and REST?

Tags: jpa, collections, entity, eclipselink, jersey-2.0

**Environment**

Jersey
Eclipselink (JPA)

**Entities**

Country --- Cities

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "countryCountryId")
private Collection<City> cityCollection;

@XmlTransient
public Collection<City> getCityCollection() {
        return cityCollection;
    }
```

**REST**

```
@GET
@Override
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public List<Country> findAll() {
    return super.findAll();
}
```

**RESULT**

```
<countries>
  <country>
   <country>Finland</country>
   <countryId>1</countryId>
   <lastUpdate>2013-08-30T00:43:35+03:00</lastUpdate>
  </country>
 <country>
  <country>Sweden</country>
  <countryId>2</countryId>
  <lastUpdate>2013-08-30T00:43:35+03:00</lastUpdate>
 </country>
</countries>
```

**QUESTION**

Why there is no Cities at all even if there is field for it?

How can I get cities as well in same @GET?

Is it even possible, I think so?

Thanks
Sami

Comment: Default setting of relationship loading is LAZY. Have you populated your related entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@XmlTransient---> **THIS OFF!**
public Collection<City> getCityCollection() {
        return cityCollection;
    }
```

@XmlTransient off and I moved it to:

```
@XmlTransient
public Country getCountryCountryId() {
    return countryCountryId;
}
```

And it is working :)